# UITableViewHeaderFooterView appearance

Tags: ios, objective-c, tableview

I'm using the following code `[[UITableViewHeaderFooterView appearance] setTintColor:[UIColor whiteColor]];` at the end of `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions` to set the tint color of a custom `UITableViewHeaderFooterView` my main problem is when i'm scrolling the table view and for example section 0 gets off the screen then reverts to default gray color any ideas how to fix this my reusable code is very basic

```
- (UIView *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView viewForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section
 {
    ListSectionHeaderView *sectionHeaderView = [self.tableView dequeueReusableHeaderFooterViewWithIdentifier:@"ListSectionHeaderView"];
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

you have to create the header footer first run then reuse it

```
- (UIView *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView viewForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section
 {

    ListSectionHeaderView *sectionHeaderView = [self.tableView dequeueReusableHeaderFooterViewWithIdentifier:@"ListSectionHeaderView"];
    if (!sectionHeaderView)
    {
         //// initialize the header here if the reuse return nil 
         sectionHeaderView = ....
    }
    ///// also you have to return it
    return sectionHeaderView;
 }
```

Comment: i'm doing the same thing